# Renderizar index principal de un proyecto Angular en un proyecto Node

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, express

Tengo un proyecto el cual hice siguiendo un tutorial, el cual es `Angular` en el **frontend**, y `Node(Express)` en el **backend**. Los proyectos funcionan sin ningún problema, pero cada uno ejecutándose de manera independiente. Quisiera que al correr el proyecto de `Node`, usando

`npm run dev`

Se renderizará el `index.html` principal del proyecto angular. Sé que existe esto mediante lo que se conoce como **SSR**, *Server Side Rendering*, pero por más que trato de llamar al archivo de multiples formas al proyecto `Node` no lo consigo.

[image: Index.js Node]

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has probado la funcion sendFile en lugar de render?
imagino que lo que quieres hacer es servir el index principal para que funcione el front (Angular) y luego consuma la api Bakcend (Node), ten en cuenta las rutas expuestas para el consumo del front.

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Comment: Use el `sendFile`, pero según alguien me dijo, que debería primero hacer la `build` de la App de angular, la cual tengo en una carpeta llamada **Dist** dentro de la carpeta **frontend**, pero igual por más ruta que ponga y todo eso, sigue igual, ya mismo hago lo que indicas y te comento.

Comment: Amigo funcionó, usando tu recomendación y la de un usuario en el sitio en ingles. Más luego pongo la respuesta de que fue todo lo que hice